# Filtering jpa built-in rest resources

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Trying to expose a repository rest resource.

I want the methods `findAll()` and `findById()` to be public (accessible even if the user is not connected) and the rest of the methods to be accessible only when authenticated user has ROLE_ADMIN

```
@RepositoryRestResource
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public interface FilliereServices extends JpaRepository<Filliere, Integer> {

    @PreAuthorize("permitAll")
    public List<Filliere> findAll();

    @PreAuthorize("permitAll")
    public Optional<Filliere> findById(Integer id);
}
```

localhost:8080/fillieres is not accessible as expected, but localhost:8080/fillieres/search/findAll throw an

`org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException`

I've tried `@RestResource(path="findAll")` on `findAll()`, but same problem.
However if i add only `@Query("FROM Filliere")`, it works like a charm.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you override the `JpaRepository` default methods then you override the the behaviours of the default REST endpoints. These methods will **NOT** appear under the `search` path.
`findAll()` is used when you try to access the `localhost:8080/fillieres`, `findById(Integer id)` is used when you call localhost:8080/fillieres/{id}.

Comment: Thanks for the information, is there any way to make them appear (under or not under search path) without having to mark them with @Query annotation ?

Comment: You have to use different method name.

Comment: what can i use as name to have same bevahior as findAll for example (without using @Query)?

Comment: `findAllByIdIsNotNull` could work. You can use `@RestResource` to rename the actual path to something more simple.